# Multiple opened windows forms & C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I’m trying to design a feature in my C# application. If the user has multiple forms opened, like for example 3 forms. I want to use the click event to position the 3 forms side to side fitting the screen. I can do that if I determined 3 forms for the incident. But I want to apply the feature towards (any) multiple opened forms.. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can get the screen the form is on using Screen.FromControl(this), you can get the screen's bounds, you can size your forms by dividing the screen size by the number of forms and you can lay them out using Location property. Remember if you're opening them to set the start position to Manual

Comment: are you using MDI container?

Comment: Use an [MDI form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and set the layout to `System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.Horizontal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MDI container for solving this problem,
for example,
Create main form and set it's  IsMdiContainer property value to "true",
for adding child forms you may use like this code:

```
            var frm = new ChildForm();
            frm.MdiParent = this;
            frm.Show();
```

For changing child forms position:

```
           var a = 0;
            var b = 0;
            foreach (var form in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                form.Location = new Point(a, b);
                a = a + form.Width + 5;
            }
```

[image]

result after click "Side to side position" button:
[image]

Comment: Hi Mike85, if this solution worked for you, please remember to mark it as the answer :)